# how to set set max counter and change TextView if max value is reached

Tags: android, for-loop, counter

If value of counter is more than maxCount the textView will change. 
this is my code. I hope you understand what I mean. thx.

```
int counter = 0;
int maxCount = 5;
TextView  txtCount, txtResult;
private Vibrator mVibrator;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tasbih);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_btn);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mVibrator.vibrate(700);
            counter ++;
            txtCount.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

         for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++ ){

                if (counter >= maxCount) {
                    txtResult.setText("Text 2");
                    counter = 0;
                    break;
                  }else if (counter >= maxCount){
                    txtResult.setText("Text 3");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.class, "Done!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using while loop

basically remove for loop
and place this condition

```
    while(counter <= maxcounter) {
//your code to set textview value
counter++; //incrementing counter value in each loop 
}
```

Comment: So if I will counting again (for twice) then change TextView, what I should I do with my code? thx

Comment: "If value of counter is more than maxCount the textView will change. "

this is your question if am reading correctly

Comment: 1 - declare boolean variable and set to falseput my example code inside

Comment: 1 - declare boolean variable and set to false

2-  write a for loop and run it for 2 times

3 - put my example while loop code inside that for loop and check for boolean value condition if true or false within the while loop (for first time it should be false as for loop is executed first time)

4 - after first run of for loop, set boolean value to true (outside while loop and within for loop)

Comment: can you explain it into the code please.. sorry I am newbie android developer. thx before

Answer (score 0):

I'm not realy sure what u mean but there is an error in yoor code.

```
if (counter >= maxCount) {
    txtResult.setText("Text 2");
    counter = 0;
    break;
  }else if (counter >= maxCount){
    txtResult.setText("Text 3");
}
```

You used same condison for if and else if. And for solution for cheking conter limit you can use while loop.

Comment: I want to do counting again for twice and change the TextView, So I should I do with my code? thx

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `TextView` bind code !

You need to bind your `TextView` like below:

```
txtCount=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
txtResult=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
.....
```

Comment: I am done do that, and how about my looping, please correct me. thx

Comment: please provide full code which you implement so user can understand problem and give proper answer.

Comment: I want my output is when I click button and the counter running then when the counter is reached my countMax the TextView will change till countMax reached again so other TextView will change again. Sorry if my English is bad. thx a lot.